# How to create my first library on GitHub and npm in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to build a simple basic library in Javascript/Typescript and about colors conversion.

For example, some of my functions (and types) I want to export are:

```
export type HEX = string;
export type RGB = { r: number; g: number; b: number };
export type RGBA = { r: number; g: number; b: number; a: number };
export type COLOR = HEX | RGB | RGBA;
// other types ...

export const hex2rgb = (hex: HEX): RGB => {
  const m = hex.match(/\w\w/g);
  if (m === null) throw new Error("");
  const [r, g, b] = m.map(x => parseInt(x, 16));
  return { r: r, g: g, b: b };
}

export const hex2rgba = (hex: HEX, alpha = 1): RGBA => {
  const [r, g, b] = hex.match(/\w\w/g).map(x => parseInt(x, 16));
  return { r: r, g: g, b: b, a: alpha };
};

// other functions...
```

I would like to create a library on GitHub/Npm that allows users to use these methods.
How can I do?
What should the project structure, folders, files, etc. be? And then how do I create a library?
I never did it and I need help.. I tried searching on the internet but it is not clear to me.

For now I'm using a Codesandbox in React (although I don't really need React)

---

So basically the structure of my code could be:

```
project
|_ src
   |_ index.ts contains all of my functions
   |_ types.ts contains types
|_ test contains some test code
```

And then? I have to create `package.js`? How?
I for example, I want to use also `Lodash`?

Comment: It could be as simple as a single file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with the npm docs. In general here are the steps

> - Create a `package.json` file
> - Create the file that will be loaded when your module is required by another application
> - Test your module.

For complete explanation refer to [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edit my main message, can you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript/typescript code can be shared with other parties using the `NPM` registry. The have published a guide for publishing packages:
https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry

There will be extra steps involved when using typescript, you will have to transpile your code using `webpack` or any other bundler.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edit my main message, can you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing your library is actually a process of few steps. However, the full development life cycle depend on many factors such as your dependencies, test platform, version of JS/Typescript etc.

Here is a good tutorial about the whole development life cycle including npm publishing.

https://hackernoon.com/publish-your-own-npm-package-946b19df577e

> Once your code is thoroughly tested, it is ready to be published.
>
> Create an account in npmjs.com. Run this command from the terminal
>
> `npm login`
>
> Enter your username and password. This will store the
>   credentials so you don’t have to enter it for every publish.
>
> Now to publish, run
>
> `npm publish`
>
> This will publish your package to NPM
>   registry. Once publish completes(in less than a minute), you can go
>   check your package in the link
>   https://www.npmjs.com/~{username}/{package-name}.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edit my main message, can you help me again?

Comment: package.json is needed when installing dependencies when npm install. I think you need that in test folder.